# Java regex Pattern not matching after having two \\p{Punct}'s in pattern?

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to validate an address TextField with the correct format based on location, and my patterns are working for all countries but United Kingdom. I'm not exactly sure what's going on here. I've tried using different regex and cannot seem to find a solution.
The format I am going for is "123 ABC Street, Greenwich, London".

Here's some code that's working for United States' address format:

```
Pattern r = Pattern.compile("\d+\s\w+\s\w+\p{Punct}\s\w+\s\w+"); 
Matcher m = r.matcher(customerAddressText.getText());
if (m.find()) {    
    customerAddress = customerAddressText.getText();
} else {    
    throw new Exception();
}
```

This code isn't working correctly for United Kingdom's address format:

```
//FIXME NOT WORKING CORRECTLY
Pattern r = Pattern.compile("\d+\s\w+\s\w+\p{Punct}\s\w+\p{Punct}\s\w+");
Matcher m = r.matcher(customerAddressText.getText());
if (m.find()) {    
    customerAddress = customerAddressText.getText();
} else {    
    throw new Exception();
}
```

Comment: does that code compile? you are aware that two back-slashes are needed in regular expressions? - it seems to work if using double back-slashes: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oeF4Y.png) - more details in the dedicated section of the documentation [Backslashes, escapes, and quoting](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#bs)

Answer (score 1):

What you want is completely impossible.

Addresses just aren't like that.

Even if your regex did 'work', it requires that streets consist of exactly 2 words (they don't), that all places have a house number (they don't), that all town/city names consist of exactly one word (they don't), and that all towns are split up into areas (they definitely don't).

Addresses are notoriously difficult. Nothing is true - not all addresses have streets, or numbers. For example, in Dubai, most addresses are *literally* a drawn picture (it's the only thing you can put on the front of your envelope that will get the mail to the right location).

Hence, trying to write a regex to find street addresses? Utterly, completely impossible.

The right approach is to adopt the standard postage rule system. This system has the following properties:

- You get 2 lines of text. For completeness sake, let's say it's unicode.
- Generally, these lines are to be capitalized.
- There is a third line for postage service area - generally, a country name. The meaning of the first 2 lines depend entirely on the third.

Even these rules don't quite work for all locations, but it's what most international postage and IT systems have standardized on, which is why its enough to deliver mail to virtually everywhere with this system. There is no purpose or point to attempt to figure out if a line is 'valid'. The user entered it - trust that they know how to get post delivered so that they can receive it.

Your only saving grace would be if this is homework. In which case your prof / book sure picked a whopper, this is a really bad example exercise. At any rate, your code doesn't compile at all - all those backslashes need to be doubled up, in both examples.

After fixing that, your second example processes `"123 ABC Street, Greenwich, London"` just fine. If it doesn't for you, then that is not the actual street address you're working with.

Perhaps it is [0 North Castle Street, Stafford](https://www.google.com/maps/@52.8070791,-2.1253715,3a,61y,245.78h,92.28t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1seVPwTtgXsWqpC-deekWYBg!2e0!7i13312!8i6656) - which shows that even something almost everybody will tell you has to be true (that house numbers cannot be 0) is false (click that link. Note the 0 on the door, that is a real address). It also completely fails your regex: The street consists of 3 words and not 2, and the town isn't split out into an area (Greenwich) and a City (London). It's.. just a single town name (Stafford).